# Rails instance distance_to shows up as NaN sometimes on reload, geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, reload, rails-geocoder

I have an index displaying all objects with certain queries (search, order, tagged, paginate) in a table. In this table, I have the object `name` and the `distance` that object is from an address (using geocoder), calling this function:

```
def distance
    self.location.distance_to(address)
end
```

Unfortunately, a whole bunch of the distances show up as `NaN`. When I reload the page, however, they sometimes give me different objects having `NaN` for distance, or sometimes all of them are there. Why would the value for distance change upon each reload? I can't seem to figure out any pattern to when one value is `NaN` or correct. Does it have to do with the location type being a float value?

PS: Also, this only seems to happen in development mode.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have a FloatDomainError when going to a different page and then returning back to the index page in development. I checked the logs in production and it says Google Geocoding API error : over query limit, so I assume it has to do with the speed I make queries. I guess I have to cache the distance to the database itself so that I don't have to keep making queries.